# Add field/string length to logstash event

Tags: lucene, kibana, elastic-stack, string-length

I'm trying to add a string length field to an index. Ideally, I'd like to use the kibana script feature as I can 'add' this field later but I keep getting a `null_pointer_exception` with the following code... I'm trying to sort in a visualization based on the fields length.

```
doc['field'].value ? doc['field'].length() : 0
```

Is this correct?

I thought it was because my field isn't always set (sparse data), but I added the `?:0` to combat that (which didn't work)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Where did you put this code?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an scripted field in Kibana, of type int, language painless, and try this:

```
return (doc['field'].value != null? doc['field'].value.length(): 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! Where can you find a reference for what properties (value, length) the object doc supports?

Comment: I'd recommend painless docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/index.html, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html. Syntax is groovy style: http://groovy-lang.org